# AngularJS - select the first option in list that's reordered in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

I just started using Angular JS yesterday, sorry if I'm asking something obvious. What I'm trying to do is make the the first option in my select the one that's selected by default, but since it's ordered on the front-end, the wrong option is selected. I think I should be reordering the data I get back from my API call from within the controller before I select the first item?

Here's my select:

```
<select ng-model="clientsList" ng-options="c.Name for c in clients | orderBy:'Name'"></select>
```

Here's my controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = $http.jsonp('http://MY-API?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .then( function ( response ) {
        $scope.clients = response.data;
        // need to select something, unfortunately, this won't be the first option on the front end because it's re-ordered alphabetically there
        $scope.clientsList = $scope.clients[0];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just order the data in controller, using same filter:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http, orderByFilter) {
  $scope.init = $http.jsonp('http://MY-API?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .then( function ( response ) {
    $scope.clients = orderByFilter(response.data, 'Name');
    $scope.clientsList = $scope.clients[0];
  });
}

<select ng-model="clientsList" ng-options="c.Name for c in clients"></select>
```

Note: You may inject AngularJS filters inside your controllers using following notation:

```
[filterName]Filter
```

Comment: Almost 3 years later and this still works like a charm. Thank you! :)